# How to make synapse managed private endpoints privateLinkResourceId a parameter in workspace_publish branch

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-resource-manager, azure-synapse

With the latest version of the Synapse workspace deployment task in Azure DevOps it is now possible to 'deploy managed private endpoints in template'. Unfortunately the property privateLinkResourceId for the managed private endpoints is not a parameter in the TemplateParametersForWorkspace.json file in the workspace_publish branch.

I have added the file arm-template-parameters-definition.json to the main branch as suggested [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/continuous-integration-delivery-resource-manager-custom-parameters)

```
"Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/managedVirtualNetworks/managedPrivateEndpoints": {
    "properties": {
        "privateLinkResourceId": "="
    }
}
```

But I am still having no luck with the privateLinkResourceId property being a parameter in the TemplateParametersForWorkspace.json to be able to override the parameter for a different environment in the deployment.

Has anyone had any luck with this or could point me in the right direction?

Comment: The file arm-template-parameters-definition.json currently isn't available for synapse (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/continuous-integration-delivery-resource-manager-custom-parameters#:~:text=Azure%20Synapse%20Analytics), will this be available soon?

Answer (score 1):

### Answer to OP

Your issue here is that you're using a DataFactory managed private endpoint which doesn't exist in Synapse, even though they're called the same. Replace `Microsoft.DataFactory/factories` with `Microsoft.Synapse/workspaces` as follows and it should work:

```
"Microsoft.Synapse/workspaces/managedVirtualNetworks/managedPrivateEndpoints": {
    "properties": {
        "privateLinkResourceId": "="
    }
}
```

Also you might want to consider a more complete and cleaner export:

```
"Microsoft.Synapse/workspaces/managedVirtualNetworks/managedPrivateEndpoints": {
    "properties": {
        "privateLinkResourceId": "-:-privateLinkResourceId",
        "groupId": "-:-groupId",
        "fqdns": "-:-fqdns:array"
    }
}
```

### Answer to @BSCooper

You can always approve private endpoints using the Azure CLI, but you'll always need some info about the PE to find it (I ask the developers to always use standard names in the MPEs that aren't tied to the environment).

Consider the following script that approves managed private endpoints on a data factory that links to the following resources (haven't tested with Synapse because it's not needed):

> 1. Key vault: myKeyvault
> 2. Storage account: myStorage
> 3. Synapse worspace: mySynapse

```
$approvalMessage = "Auto-Approved by Azure DevOps"

#KeyVault
$keyVaultPE = (az network private-endpoint-connection list -g "myKeyVaultRG" -n "myKeyVault" --type "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults" --query "[?contains(properties.privateEndpoint.id, 'MPE_AKV')].id") | convertfrom-json
az network private-endpoint-connection approve --id $keyVaultPE --description "$approvalMessage"

#Storage
$storagePE = (az network private-endpoint-connection list -g "mystorageRG" -n "mystorage" --type "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts" --query "[?contains(properties.privateEndpoint.id, 'MPE_Blob')].id") | convertfrom-json
az network private-endpoint-connection approve --id $storagePE --description "$approvalMessage"

#Synapse
$synapsePE = (az network private-endpoint-connection list -g "mySynapseRG" -n "mySynapse" --type "Microsoft.Synapse/workspaces" --query "[?contains(properties.privateEndpoint.id, 'MPE_Synapse')].id") | convertfrom-json
az network private-endpoint-connection approve --id $synapsePE --description "$approvalMessage"
```

Notice how you can query the PEs by passing part of the name on the JmesPath, that naming convention is what I ask the devs to use in their branches. Also note that you can always change the jmespath to whatever you can use to find it.

Answer (score 0):

I have been working through this challenge myself in order to create a Dev endpoint (to obtain a static IP for my synapse pipelines).  I couldn't figure out how to make the Synapse workspace deployment task work for this requirement either, so have resorted to Powershell instead.  The process I have followed is:

**Synapse Studio**
Manually create the desired managed private endpoint (MPE) and check-in to the repo main branch (folder managedVirtualNetwork/default/managedPrivateEndpoint).  This creates an unparameterised ARM template something like the below, which will be used in the next step:

```
{
    "name": "synapse-ws-dev--~YOURWORKSPACENAME~",
    "properties": {
        "privateLinkResourceId": "/subscriptions/~YOURSUBSCRIPTIONID~/resourceGroups/~YOURRESOURCEGROUP~/providers/Microsoft.Synapse/workspaces/~YOURWORKSPACENAME~",
        "groupId": "dev"
    }
}
```

**In Azure DevOps Release Pipeline**
Add a new Azure Powershell task.  Because the cmdlet to create/update a MPE only accepts a definition file, the file created in the previous step will be amended in the release artifacts and passed to the cmdlet  (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.synapse/new-azsynapsemanagedprivateendpoint?view=azps-7.4.0&viewFallbackFrom=azps-7.3.0)

```
$mpeName = "synapse-ws-dev--$(workspaceName)"
$armTemplateFullName = "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\scripts\managedVirtualNetwork\default\managedPrivateEndpoint\~FILENAME FROM PREVIOUS STEP~.json"

# Read the ARM Template File
$mpeArmJson = Get-Content -Path $armTemplateFullName -Raw

# Replace Placeholders
$mpeArmJson = $mpeArmJson -replace '~NAME FROM TEMPLATE~', $mpeName
$mpeArmJson = $mpeArmJson -replace '~WORKSPACE FROM privateLinkResourceId~', '$(workspaceName)'
$mpeArmJson = $mpeArmJson -replace '~SUBSCRIPTION FROM privateLinkResourceId~', '$(SubscriptionId)'
$mpeArmJson = $mpeArmJson -replace '~RESOURCE GROUP FROM privateLinkResourceId~', '$(rgName)'

# Write the Amended ARM Template File
$mpeArmJson | Set-Content -Path $armTemplateFullName

# Create the MPE (Passing Amended ARM File As Parameter)
New-AzSynapseManagedPrivateEndpoint -WorkspaceName $(workspaceName) -Name $mpeName -DefinitionFile $armTemplateFullName
```

This script will create the MPE.  Note however, that when it is first deployed it needs *manually approving* in the synapse resource (Private endpoint connections blade).  I don't know of a way round this at present.  Hopefully MS will come up with a better solution in future.